# Ubuntu Environment Is Broken

Tags: package-management, themes, environment, fakeroot

After installation, this PC's Desktop [image: picture] does not look like the Desktop on my other PC.

Comment: Are you accustomed to the GNOME Desktop https://www.gnome.org/ ?  Which version was installed on the PC in question?

Answer (score 0):

Your environment isn't broken, it's just some configuration and theme mismatch.

**For Unity :**

Choice 1 : Reset Unity by `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`, for removing compiz configuration use `rm  -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1`
`

Choice 2 : Kind of last resort, reinstall unity by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`.

To reset unity icons use : `unity --reset-icons`

**For GNOME :**

Choice 1 : Try resetting GNOME by using dconf by command `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/.`

Choice 2 : Use this command to completely delete your GNOME configs, use with caution. `rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*`

Choice 3 : Last resort, reinstall GNOME by `apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell`.